# fetch db mysql value in search input field and modifying in dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, forms

I cannot find a solution for my problem because for me it is an advanced level of programming.
I have a custom search field, but I need to 'convert it' in a dropdown menu that fetching some users values in mysql, avoiding writing hundreds of selection options.
This is the registration form field Im working it

```
<tr class="user-luogo-wrap">
<th><label for="luogo">
            Luogo:  </label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="luogo" id="luogo" value="Treviso" class="regular-text"></td>
    </tr>
```

Created with a function

```
function my_user_contactmethods( $user_contactmethods ){
$user_contactmethods['luogo'] = 'Luogo:';
return $user_contactmethods;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'my_user_contactmethods', 5);
```

and this is the field where I need to fetch the 'luogo' mysql values and modifying it in dropdown

```
<div class="um-search-filter um-text-filter-type "> <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="luogo" name="luogo" placeholder="Luogo" value="" class="um-form-field" aria-label="Luogo"></div>
```

I hope I have explained it well. Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like https://phppot.com/jquery/bootstrap-autocomplete-with-dynamic-data-load-using-php-ajax/

Comment: Hi thank you but I don't need Autocomplete but a dropdown search data automatically generated (from a specific database value)

Comment: I explain better, How to populate a drop down list from specific registration form field or profile form field (gettin' meta key, id).

Comment: I think the autocomplete idea is good, but dont understand, in my opinion that guide is for php expert. Im tring to modifing it but don't know about ```SELECT  FROM tbl_country WHERE country_name LIKE ? ``` and how to hook your 2 php in my functions php

Answer (score 0):

In Console I have found the Form data , Request payload generated after a search action:
`directory_id=3f9fc&page=1&search=&sorting=display_name&gmt_offset=8&post_refferer=61&nonce=f47827a450&luogo=boston&action=um_get_members`

So Im trying to modify this function

```
function field_choices( $field ) {  
    // reset choices
    $field['luogo'] = array();   
    // get the textarea value from options page without any formatting
    $choices = get_field('my_select_values', 'option', false);
    // explode the value so that each line is a new array piece
    $choices = explode("\n", $choices);   
    // remove any unwanted white space
    $choices = array_map('trim', $choices);
    // loop through array and add to field 'choices'
    if( is_array($choices) ) {      
        foreach( $choices as $choice ) {           
            $field['luogo'][ $choice ] = $choice;           
        }       
    }   
    // return the field
    return $field;    
}
add_action('um_get_members', 'field_choices');
```

Is my intuition correct?